# Print the name of a parent function, inside the child function

Tags: r, function, callstack

I've figured out how to print the code of the parent function, while inside a child function:

```
a <- function(x, ...){
  print(sys.function(which=1))
  x
}
b <- function(x) a(x)
c <- function(x) a(x, param=1)

b(1)
c(1)
```

Which yields:

```
> b(1)
function(x) a(x)
[1] 1
> c(1)
function(x) a(x, param=1)
[1] 1
```

How do I print the *name* (or better yet the call) of the parent function, from the child function e.g.:

```
a <- function(x, ...){
  print(magic())
  x
}

> b(1)
b(1)
[1] 1
> c(1)
c(1)
[1] 1
```

?

Comment: Should have spent 30 more seconds reading.... `sys.calls()[[1]]`

Comment: Should I delete this question, if I figured out the answer myself?

Comment: You can post your own answer below

Answer (score 1):

`sys.calls` has the call stack:

```
a <- function(x, ...){
  print(sys.calls()[[1]])
  return(invisible())
}
b <- function(x) a(x)
c <- function(x) a(x, param=1)

b(1)
c(1)
```

Yields:

```
> b(1)
b(1)
> c(1)
c(1)
```

Expanding on my answer a little, and using Alex's answer, here is how you'd print the current call, parent call, and root call for a given function:

```
a <- function(x, named, ...){
  call_stack <- sys.calls()
  call_stack_dots_expanded <- lapply(1:length(call_stack), function(i){
    match.call(definition=sys.function(i), call=call_stack[[i]], envir=sys.frames()[[i]])
  })
  call_stack_as_text <- lapply(call_stack_dots_expanded, deparse)
  me <- call_stack_as_text[length(call_stack_as_text)]
  parent <- call_stack_as_text[length(call_stack_as_text) - 1]
  root <- call_stack_as_text[1]
  print(paste('My call is', me))
  print(paste('My parent call is', parent))
  print(paste('My root call is', root))
  return(invisible())
}
b <- function(x, named, ...) a(x, named, ...)
c <- function(x, named, ...) b(x, named, ...)
d <- function(x, named, ...) c(x, named, ...)
e <- function(x, named, ...) d(x, named, ...)
f <- function(x, named, ...) e(x, named, ...)

f(1, named=1, unnamed=2)
```

Which yields:

```
> f(1, named=1, unnamed=2)
[1] "My call is a(x = x, named = named, unnamed = 2)"
[1] "My parent call is b(x = x, named = named, unnamed = 2)"
[1] "My root call is f(x = 1, named = 1, unnamed = 2)"
```

Now the last thing to figure out is how to print the argument values all the way down the stack:

```
> f(1, named=1, unnamed=2)
[1] "My call is a(x = 1, named = 1, unnamed = 2)"
[1] "My parent call is b(x = 1, named = 1, unnamed = 2)"
[1] "My root call is f(x = 1, named = 1, unnamed = 2)"
```

Comment: Ok, now what if I want to print something like "the function that called me was b(1)"?  I can't seem to coerce the `sys.calls()[[1]]` object to character.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comments to your own answer

```
a <- function(x, ...){
    cat("I was called by", deparse(match.call()))
    return(invisible())
}
R> a(1)
I was called by a(x = 1)
```

Comment: How would I combine `sys.calls` with `match.call` to argument match every function in the whole call stack?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question. Why don't you ask a new SO question?